# Angular 6 How to Get Distance between two location AGM

Tags: angular, google-maps, distance

I get **Direction** between two points using this reference https://www.npmjs.com/package/agm-direction
Now I want to get/calculate **distance** between two location and I'm Confusing how's do it.

In **my Module**

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: 'My API Key....',
  libraries: ['geometry']
})
```

In **my Component**

```
getDirection() {
   this.origin = { lat: this.pick_latitude, lng: this.pick_longitude }
   this.destination = { lat: this.drop_latitude, lng: this.drop_longitude }
}
```

**My Question** : How I get distance between two point when I use above reference to get direction path ? Please give me suggestion ( Google map API etc). I'm using Angular 6

Comment: Its already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27943/7651583

Comment: @Ravikumar Thank You help me, Isn't has any Google Map API to get distance ?

Comment: I dont think so.

Comment: @Ravikumar that's the the proper way to do it using angular google maps. They have a library for that.

Comment: @PatricioVargas thank you!

Comment: @Ravikumar I meant that not the proper way. You can take a look to geometry on google maps or take a look to my answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use Google Geometry API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry

```
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
import { AgmCoreModule, MapsAPILoader } from "@agm/core";

calculateDistance() {
    const mexicoCity = new google.maps.LatLng(19.432608, -99.133209.);
    const jacksonville = new google.maps.LatLng(40.730610, -73.935242.);
    const distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(nyc, london);
  }
```

**for Angular 6+**

Type to add allow Angular to use the Google Maps types. In your terminal run:

```
npm i -D @types/googlemaps
```

Time to tell Angular we are ready to use the Google Maps Types. Open your tsconfig.app.json and `tsconfig.spec.json` and add googlemaps to the types array inside of the compilerOptions object.

Note: I only put it on the `tsconfig.app.json` file some people have encounter issues and have to add it to both files I mentioned above.

```
   "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["googlemaps"]
   },
```

or

Note on @Abdelsalam Shahlol comment:

> For Angular 6+, you can't do this import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
> Instead place this in top (first line) of the TS file. /// /node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts"/>

**In your app.module.ts**

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: 'YOUR API KEY',
  libraries: ['geometry']
}),
```

Comment: After Follow your instruction I got value `9616.47631361913` for ` const distance'  If I divide it 1000 I think I can get distance by **km**  Am I correct ?

Comment: @Rika correct. The distance you see it's in meters `9616.47631361913` you can divide by 1000 or multiply by `0.001`

Comment: Thank You @PatricioVargas Your answer is very helpful  for me,If you can Please tell me is there has any method to get **duration**  like distance.

Comment: by duration you mean how long would it take to get from point a to point b? @Rika

Comment: Yes, Simply Time

Comment: well..by car, walking or flying?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182128/discussion-between-rika-and-patricio-vargas).

Comment: why is MapsAPILoader  being required? where is it used?
Im dealing with the same question.

Comment: For Angular 6+, you can't do this `import {} from '@types/googlemaps';` 
Instead place this in top (first line) of the TS file.

`/// <reference path=".<relative_path>/node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts"/>`

Answer (score 3):

You can do a straight line distance with maths, you don't need to use the Google API and use up any "credit" doing it.

Here's a lat/long to lat/long function I wrote for use in Angular 6+:

```
  asTheCrowFlies(x1: number, y1: number, x2: number, y2: number) {
var result = 0;
const RADIANS: number = 180 / 3.14159265;
const METRES_IN_MILE: number = 1609.34;

if (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2) {
  result = 0;

} else {
  // Calculating Distance between Points
  var lt1 = x1 / RADIANS;
  var lg1 = y1 / RADIANS;
  var lt2 = x2 / RADIANS;
  var lg2 = y2 / RADIANS;

  // radius of earth in miles (3,958.8) * metres in a mile * position on surface of sphere...
  result = (3958.8 * METRES_IN_MILE) * Math.acos(Math.sin(lt1) * Math.sin(lt2) + Math.cos(lt1) * Math.cos(lt2) * Math.cos(lg2 - lg1));
}
return result; }
```

If you take out the "miles to metres" multiple, the answer is in miles. You only need the Google API for ROAD distances and that's not done with the MAP API which AGM uses, instead you need the ROUTE API from Google. I have not yet seen an Angular component for the ROUTE API; most people just write a service with the API calls.

Comment: Good solution! Thank you.